# Unable to Overwrite File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm unable to get this exercise running properly:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print(f"We're going to erase {filename}.")
print("If you don't want that, CRTL-C (^C).")
print("If you do want that, hit RETURN.")

input("?")

print("Opening the file...")
target = open(filename, 'w')

print("Truncating the file. Goodbye!")
target.truncate()

print("Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.")

line1 = input("line 1: ")
line2 = input("line 2: ")
line3 = input("line 3: ")

print("I'm going to write these to the file.")

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print("And finally, we close it")
target.close()
```

When I run this, it doesn't actually overwrite the file. It creates a new file that includes the three lines I entered. I know truncate is supposed to empty the file, so I don't know why ut's creating another file. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong, let me know. Thanks

Comment: Are the file and script in the same directory? I tried it with them in the same directory and it worked as expected.

Comment: This code worked perfectly for me!

Comment: They are in the same directory. I'm entering: python ex16.py test.txt into the powershell and I'm getting two files. It's not actually overwriting the file when I run it.

Comment: what is the file name you want to overwrite? Try this. make a new text file in the same folder as ex16.py calles `SO.txt` and put make its only contents `Man I hope this works!`. Then, in powershell, run `python ex16.py SO.txt` and go through the program.I'm asking this just to be certain text file names are the same.

Comment: Make sure you're showing file extensions.

Comment: OK, I just figured out the problem. I kept saving the files with ".txt" on the end. When I removed that it works fine now. Thanks